# Найти поля, значения которых являются подстрокой заданной строки

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, search

Здравствуйте. Немного поясню вопрос: требуется найти в таблице такие строки, значение некоторого поля в которых являются подстрокой заданной строки.

Пример таблицы:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| ID | WORD    | SOMEVALUE |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 1  | ABCD    | 1002      |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 2  | ABCDEFJ | 29412     |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 3  | ABCDE   | 417       |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Требуется выбрать строки, в которых значение поля WORD является подстрокой **"ABCDEF"** (т.е. строки 1,3).

С такой проблемой сталкиваюсь в первые, поэтому даже не представляю, с чего начать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `where 'ABCDEF' like concat('%',word,'%')` ну или первый процент не нужен, если надо строго с начала

Comment: "А Ларчик просто открывался"... Большое спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос:

> [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike): where 'ABCDEF' like concat('%',word,'%')